# Unable to create new Team Project - TF30170 and TF249061

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We recently ungraded and moved TFS from 2013 update 4 to TFS 2015 Update 1.  When trying to create a new Team Project we keep getting the error below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Error
>
> TF30170: The plugin Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Reporting failed
> during task Populate Reports from group Reporting.
>
> Explanation
>
> Plugin error text: “TF249061: You cannot access the
> following report item: /Tfs2010OlapReportDS. Access was denied because
> your account does not have one or more permissions required to access
> this item.”
>
> User Action
>
> Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

Comment: Do you need help reading the error text? See also [ServerFault: Cannot create a project TFS 2012 - TF218027](http://serverfault.com/questions/432496/cannot-create-a-project-tfs-2012-tf218027).

Comment: The error message makes sense to me, I just can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I was able to determine the issue and was able to fix it.  Had to grant access to Tfs2010OlapReportDS which was a chore its self.

Comment: Feel free to post a self-answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the current service account had access to all the data sets except for Tfs2010OlapReportDS.  To grant access to that I had to log into the report manager and grant access to service account using the old service account that was used on the previous installation of TFS.

Comment: Where did you find this dataset?